# Как обработать AttributeError: 'NoneType' при парсинге csv Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, csv, beautiful-soup

```
url = get_url(d)
def get_title(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
    ol = soup.find('ol', 'breadcrumb')
    title = ol.find_all('li')[-1].string
    return title
title = get_title(url)
```

При парсинге при помощи [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/csv.html), функция, не найдя на некоторых страницах нужного элемента, возвращает следующую ошибку:

```
title = ol.find_all('li')[-1].string
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

На этой странице, действительно, нету нужного элемента, однако, я не понимаю, как обрабатывать подобные случаи.

Задача, по крайней мере, вернуть пустую строчку, `None` или `False` - без разницы. Лишь бы парсинг прошёл до конца.

Comment: Используйте связку `try/except`? В блоке except: `except AttributeError: return False`

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодаря подсказке [approximatenumber](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199091/approximatenumber), удалось решить задачу следующим образом:

```
url = get_url(d)
def get_title(url):
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
        ol = soup.find('ol', 'breadcrumb')
        title = ol.find_all('li')[-1].string
    except AttributeError: return False
    return title
title = get_title(url)
```

Comment: Ловля AttributeError это хак (не стоит злоупотреблять), который баги в коде может скрывать. Тестируйте явно `ol is None` вместо этого.